# what is the solution for child exception error?

Tags: authentication, asp-classic

What about the "child exception error" when I move from page to another,?
I read this topic:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320439

and I tried to use :
HttpContext.Current.RewritePath, FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage and response.redirect, but I didnt get any result for my problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Response.Redirect()` method to solve this problem.

Comment: I use it, and it works correctly within the same level of directory, but there still a problem , such as:

I'am on the root of solution where Login.aspx and folder student on the same level

now I want to go to the page situated in :
-login
-student-->Home.aspx

I appreciate your help, and thank you for your time